# PHP looking for best way to use 'goto' to skip PHP script

Tags: php, html, exit, goto, skip

I am looking for the best way to 'skip' a PHP script to pass directly to my HTML code. Here's an example:

```
<?php 
include 'ws/main.php';
include 'ws/database/connection.php';

$error = false;
$routes = getCurrentParameters();

if (!isset($routes[0]) && !$error) 
{
    $error = traduction("No promotion entered in the URL");
    goto end;
}
else if (!isset($routes[1]) && !$error)
{
    $error = traduction("No page entered in the URL");
    goto end;
}

if (!$error) 
{
    $result = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM promotion WHERE name = '$routes[0]'");
    $promo = $result->fetch_row();
    
    if (empty($promo) && !$error) 
    {
        $error = traduction("The promotion '". $routes[0] ."' do not exist");
        goto end;
    }
    else if (!file_exists("page/" . $routes[1] . ".php"))
    {
        $error = traduction("The page '". $routes[1] ."' do not exist");
        goto end;
    }
    
    $result = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM traduction WHERE promotion_id = $promo[0]");
    $traduction = $result->fetch_all();
}

end:
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Start CSS import -->
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='<?php echo BASE_PATH ?>assets/css/bootstrap.css' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='<?php echo BASE_PATH ?>assets/css/font-awesome.css' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='<?php echo BASE_PATH ?>assets/css/animate.css' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='<?php echo BASE_PATH ?>assets/css/main.css' />
    <!-- End CSS import -->
</head>
<body>
    <?php if (!$error) // If the app do not catch any error
    {
        include "page/$routes[1].php";
    }
    else // If the app already catch an error
    {
        // Include the error.php page
        include "page/error.php";
    } ?>

    <!-- Start JS import -->
    <script type='application/javascript' src='<?php echo BASE_PATH ?>assets/js/jquery.js'></script>
    <script type='application/javascript' src='<?php echo BASE_PATH ?>libs/js/tether/dist/js/tether.js'></script>
    <script type='application/javascript' src='<?php echo BASE_PATH ?>assets/js/bootstrap.js'></script>
    <script type='application/javascript' src='<?php echo BASE_PATH ?>assets/js/moment.js'></script>
    <script type='application/javascript' src='<?php echo BASE_PATH ?>assets/js/bootbox.js'></script>
    <script type='application/javascript' src='<?php echo BASE_PATH ?>assets/js/sweetalert.js'></script>
    <script type='application/javascript' src='<?php echo BASE_PATH ?>assets/js/main.js'></script>
    <!-- End JS import -->

    <script>
        $(".img").css("background", "url(<?php echo $promo[2]; ?>) no-repeat center center")
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

So, if you have read all my code, which is not complicated at all, I am just looking for the best way to quit my PHP script, in the top, to go directly to my HTML code when I have an issue in my database or the information just do not match. Currently I use the 'goto' method with a tag 'end:' in the end of the script. I know that 'goto' method isn't optimal at all, so I'm looking for a better way to do it because I'm pretty sure there's already an existing method.

Comment: Does PHP provides `goto`? What for?

Comment: why do you need the `goto`? you already have the `if (!$error)` around that part of the script you want to skip

Comment: [mandatory link to xkcd's "goto" comic strip](https://xkcd.com/292/)

Comment: it's even in the doc: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php (the xkcd)

Comment: @KarstenKoop I need something like `goto` because my code isn't finish yet, I still have toons of things to add. I just need a simple way to get out of my PHP script without quitting the HTML code.

Comment: Will `break;` work? If not, you probably will need to restructure or refactor your code, so that you *won't* need to "goto end"

Answer (score 1):

If you put the code you potentially want to run into a function, or as a method in a class, then it's a simple matter to run that code - or choose to return out of it early, without doing anything.

```
<?php
function doThings($error, $routes) {
{
    $traduction = array();
    if (!isset($routes[0]) && !$error) {
        return $traduction;  // leave the function without doing anything
    }

    // the rest of the checks and actions, to get the database results

    return $traduction;
}

$traduction = doThings($error, $routes);

// loop over the (maybe empty $traduction variable) to output
?>
```